# SecurityException is thrown when I call startIntent on another apps intent

Tags: java, android, android-sharing

My app acts as an app chooser, replacing the default android share menu:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

In this activity, I grab the Intent and then share it to another app:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Parcelable parcelable = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
Intent newIntent = (Intent) parcelable;
        shareIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, activityName));
        startActivity(shareIntent);
        finish();
```

This works pretty well, except for when I get shared a content URI. Then my app crashes:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10628 does not have permission to content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/15303956193093126976530267588801.jpg [user 0]
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1958)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4884)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1617)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4522)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:741)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
```

It looks like my app doesn't get permissions to this URI, so `startActivity` cant be executed for some reason. What can I do to prevent this? Is there a way to send the intent to the normal Android Share menu in those occasions?

Answer (score 0):

Call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)` on your `Intent` before calling `startActivity()`.